# Understanding the shape of $\phi''(x)=F(\phi(x))$

Tags: optimization, symmetry, differential

Hello I've got a question and no idea to get a solution. Maybe someone can give me an advice.

The following problem is given:

There is given a function $\phi \in C^2([a,b])$. Furthermore there is a $C^2$-function F (sufficiently well-defined).
And there is the following relation: $\phi''(x)=F(\phi(x))$   (1)

The statement is: By differential equation (1) it is clear that every function $\phi$ that satisfies these requirements will have the following described shape:

$\phi(x)$ is even with respect to any local maximum or minimum, so that its graph is symmetric with respect to vertical lines through such maxima and minima. (image)

[image]

So, I've got no idea how to prove that statement. I would be grateful for every hint.

Answer (score 1):

This is the equation of motion of a physical system. You multiply with the derivative and integrate (this only works for space dimension one) to obtain
$$
\tfrac12ϕ'(x)^2+V(ϕ(x))=E=const.
$$
where $V$ is an anti-derivative of $-F$, or $F(y)=-\nabla V(y)$.

Now the curves $$p=\pm\sqrt{2E-2V(y)}$$ parametrize the level sets of constant energy $E$ in the $(y,p)$ phase space, and any trajectory will be bound to stay on one energy level, which is fixed by the initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

We are given the second order ODE
$$y''(x)=F\bigl(y(x)\bigr)\ ,\tag{1}$$
where $F$ is continuous on a suitable $y$-interval. Assume that $x\mapsto\phi(x)$ is a solution of $(1)$ in some open $x$-interval, and that $\phi$ has a local extremum at $x_0$. Then by the general existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs this $\phi$ is *the* solution of the initial problem $(1)\wedge(2)$, where the initial conditions are given by
$$y(x_0)=\phi(x_0),\quad y'(x_0)=0\ .\tag{2}$$
Consider now the function $\psi$ obtained by reflecting the graph of $\phi$ at the vertical $x=x_0$:
$$\psi(x):=\phi(2x_0 -x)\qquad\bigl(|x-x_0|<h\bigr)\ .$$
One computes $\psi(x_0)=\phi(x_0)$, then $\psi'(x)=-\phi'(2x_0-x)$, and in particular $\psi'(x_0)=0$. Finally one has
$$\psi''(x)=\phi''(2x_0-x)=F\bigl(\phi(2x_0-x)\bigr)=F\bigl(\psi(x)\bigr)\ ,$$
which establishes $\psi$ as "another" solution of $(1)\wedge(2)$. It follows that in fact $\psi(x)\equiv\phi(x)$, in other words, that the graph of $\phi$ is symmetric with respect to the vertical $x=x_0$.